# (un)named pipe between dotnet core 3.1 (Linux arm) and gnu c++ (same machien, Linux arm)

Tags: c#, c++, linux, .net-core

I've been researching for some time, and most nice examples deal with same language code. The present problem however is somewhat different, the goal is to send fixed-size integers (UInt16 or UInt32), one at the time, from c# on dotnet core running under Linux arm to simple c++ compiled using gnu c++ compiler. c# sends a specific value via pipe and the c++ program receives the values and some action is taken.

The anonymous pipe on the c++ side works with file descriptors, and I tried using a NamedPipeClientStream() using the same "filename" (pipename) on the c# side. Trying to open the pipe on c# eventually causes a timeout exception:

sender, c#, dotnet core 3.1:

```
    using System.IO.Pipes;
    public NamedPipeClientStream pipe;
    pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "fifoChannel", PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.WriteThrough);
    pipe.ConnectAsync();
    ...// later
    Byte[] values = { 2, 3, 4, 5}; // mimic UInt32
    pipe.Write(values);
```

receiver, c++:

```
    const char* file = "./fifoChannel";
    int fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
    ...// later
    ssize_t count = read(fd, &next, sizeof(int));
    // nothing arrives
```

I created ('touch'ed) the file `./fifoChannel` and both executables run from the same directory, and set it to -rw-rw-rw-. The receiver-side nothing comes in, but no exception occurs; on the sender side it seems unable to open the pipe. Attempting to write to the pipe yields an "Pipe hasn't connected yet" exception.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can’t create a FIFO with `touch`; try `mkfifo`?

Comment: I learned along the way that it's not a "file" in the sense it can be "touched". I ended up using (what worked very well to my surprise) dllimport and unmanaged code, I created a shared library on the Linux-side, exposed what I needed and just called it from the managed code... I did try the mkfifo but did not make a difference, still wasn't working. Cheers!